# visualize decision surface of neural network

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica, neural-network, visualization

Where can I find a program that visualizes (ie, plots) the decision boundary surface of a 2-layer feed-forward neural network?  With 1 layer the decision surface is just a bunch of straight lines.  But with 2 layers (and possibly sigmoid thresholds for each neuron), the decision surface can be very complex and non-linear, even disjoint I guess.  It would be nice to have an interactive tool to get a hands-on "feel" on the network... both for educational purposes and research :)

Comment: You could simply plot a heatmap of the predicted probabilites. I think that would even be a better visualization (it is only possible for 2 dimensions though). Example: http://youtu.be/MkLJ-9MubKQ

Answer (score 0):

It depends from the way, your neural network is implemented. If to trust your tags, you used wolfram-mathematica for implementation. It has some tools for visualisation: 
http://www.wolfram.com/training/courses/vis411.html
http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPointPlot3D.html etc...
For C# visualisation I use http://ilnumerics.net/
And for visualisation in Octave I use built in function mesh ( for 3d ) and plot for 2D.
You just need to choose what to plot. Predicted values, input values, average of two, three, four input values.